# Class ClockTriggerBuilder: Specific Date and Time (only once) Trigger in Google Sheet Script keeps repeatedly executing every minute

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script, and trigger, run as intended at the first instance. But then it does not stop! The trigger keeps executing once every minute thereafter!

I only need it to run ONCE, as programmed, and that's it!
How do I stop the trigger from executing after the first, intended execution?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
PS: This is my first attempt at writing a Google Sheet Script, so please make the answer simple to understand!

```
function sendWAnow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
var Date = sheet1.getRange(3,3).getValue();  
var subject = sheet1.getRange(4,3).getValue();
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(5,3).getValue();
var message = sheet1.getRange(6,3).getValue();
ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendWAnow')
           .timeBased()
           .at(Date)
           .create();  
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: I just realized something: I have used sendWAnow as both a function and also as a Trigger name. Could this be causing the problem? If so, what's a simple solution?

Comment: Can you check in the Stackdriver page undert MyTriggers section if the trigger has been created? Are you sure the Date in range 3,3 is correctly formatted? Maybe you will need to pass it as a string to a `new Date(string)` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your code operates as an infinite loop of triggers. The first time you execute `sendWAnow()` it will create a trigger which will execute `sendWAnow()` and then a new trigger will be created again.

---

### Solution:

You should split the two functions, the one should create a trigger for the other one.

Execute **only** `createTrigger()`:

```
function createTrigger(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
var Date = sheet1.getRange(3,3).getValue(); 
ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendWAnow')
           .timeBased()
           .at(Date)
           .create();
}
```

that will trigger `sendWAnow()` at the particular time.

```
function sendWAnow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
var Date = sheet1.getRange(3,3).getValue();  
var subject = sheet1.getRange(4,3).getValue();
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(5,3).getValue();
var message = sheet1.getRange(6,3).getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Allesandro and Marios. I tried both your suggestions. While there was no issue creating the Scripts by either method (meaning no errors), neither seems to be creating a trigger. In other words, the Trigger is not executing--not even once! I'm wondering why!

Comment: Hi Guys, When I made the following two modifications, my Trigger has started working as intended. One, I added this as the first line of code:  
 function createTimeDrivenTrigger() { .....and second, I added a built-in Trigger in the Google Sheet Script: From Spreadsheet-On Form Submit. That did the trick.  Many thanks for your guidance!!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You are recursively calling your function without an end condition.

Since you just want to run this function once the best solution would be create another function (maybe called `main()`) which only task is to set up the Time Driven trigger.

For example:

```
function main() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
    var Date = sheet1.getRange(3,3).getValue();  
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendWAnow')
           .timeBased()
           .at(Date)
           .create();  
}
```

### Reference

[Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))